# Trying to update a database via AJAX and Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to achieve something basic, where you submit a form with a weight and it updates my database via ajax.

I've been looking through some of the answered questions for guidance but I just can't figure out why the below code doesn't work.

looking in chrome developer tools it look like it's not even submitting the form properly, so I don't think its the php script that's the issue (although it may have other issues once I fix the first problem).

Any help with fixing this would be much appreciated.

Here's the form and Ajax code

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#weight_tracker_form").submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../weight_tracker_process.php",
        data: {
            weight: $("#weight").attr("value"),
        },
        success: function(){
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("error");
        }
    });
    return false;
});

</script>


<h2>Weight Tracker</h2>

<form id="weight_tracker_form" method="post">
            Date: <input autofocus id="date" name="date" type="date"/>
            Weight: <input id="weight" name="weight" type="text"/> Kg
            <input type="submit" value="Submit Weight">
</form>
```

And here's the script weight_tracker_process.php

```
<?php
    // configuration
require("includes/config.php");

    if ($_POST["weight"] == NULL)
    {
        apologize("Please enter an email");
    }

    $weight = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["weight"]);
    $date = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["date"]);
    if (query("INSERT INTO weight (user_id, weight_measurement) VALUES (?, ?)",         $_SESSION["id"], $weight); == false){
        echo "Update Error";
    }
    else {
        echo "Success";
    }   

?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: In your jQuery data, you don't need a trailing comma on the last one, so it would be `data:{ weight: $("#weight").attr("value") }`

Comment: **pdo** or **mysqli** ??

Comment: It is not the script, it works right away if I reproduce it, pass a weight and return it back. Bt you should place the code in a document ready OR after your markup!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is your exact code, then what's probably happening is the handler isn't being attached to the `form` element.  The JavaScript code is before the `form`, so when it runs the `form` doesn't exist yet.  So this selector returns an empty array:

```
$("#weight_tracker_form")
```

You'll want to wait until the DOM is finished loading before assigning the event handler:

```
$(function () {
    $("#weight_tracker_form").submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../weight_tracker_process.php",
            data: {
                weight: $("#weight").attr("value"),
            },
            success: function(){
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("error");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Wrapping it in the jQuery function like this will cause it to wait until the document's ready event fires.

Comment: You are right, instinctively placed the script after the markup, so didnt realized it :(

Comment: Thanks now the jquery is executing but it's giving me a "error" alert, does this mean the php script isn't executing properly?

Comment: @user2803072: What's the error?  In your browser debugging tools you can inspect the response coming back from the server.

Comment: @user2803072: Check your PHP logs then.  It's a separate issue from the original, but basically your server-side code is now throwing an error somewhere.  You're not really trapping that error, so it's probably in the system's PHP logs.  (Note: The use of `alert("error");` in the client-side code also isn't effective error trapping.  You'll want to capture as much information as possible when a runtime failure occurs, not just indicate that a failure occurred at all and be done with it.)

Comment: could it be the permissions on the script? It's -rw-r--r-- at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Try switch this:

```
weight: $("#weight").attr("value");
```

For this:

```
weight: $("#weight").val();
```

Also, you put the code on in document.ready. Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function({
        $("#weight_tracker_form").submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../weight_tracker_process.php",
            data: {
                weight: $("#weight").attr("value"),
            },
            success: function(){
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("error");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, initial problem was as you suggested with me forgetting to wait for the dom to load before executing the script.
Second problem was some small bracket and syntax errors in the script.

Final code is below

HTML / Jquery

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#weight_tracker_form").submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "weight_tracker_process.php",
            data: {
                weight: $("#weight").val()
            },
            success: function(){
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("error");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});

</script>


<h2>Weight Tracker</h2>

<form id="weight_tracker_form" method="post">
            Date: <input autofocus id="date" name="date" type="date"/>
            Weight: <input id="weight" name="weight" type="text"/> Kg
            <input type="submit" value="Submit Weight">
</form>

<a href="logout.php">Log Out</a>
```

PHP

```
<?php
    // configuration
require("includes/config.php");

// if form was submitted
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    if ($_POST["weight"] == NULL)
    {
        echo "Error";
    }

    $weight = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["weight"]);
    if (query("INSERT INTO weight (user_id, weight_measurement) VALUES(?, ?)", $_SESSION["id"], $weight) == false){
        echo "Update Error";
    }
    else {
        echo "Success";
    }   
}  
else
{
    // else render form
    printf("error");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also suggest to use jQuery.serialize() method to post all the fields from broser to the server.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#weight_tracker_form").submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../weight_tracker_process.php",
            data: $("#weight_tracker_form").serialize(),
            success: function(){
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("error");
            }
        });
        debugger;
        return false;
    });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <h2>Weight Tracker</h2>

    <form id="weight_tracker_form" method="post">
                Date: <input autofocus id="date" name="date" type="date"/>
                Weight: <input id="weight" name="weight" type="text"/> Kg
                <input type="submit" value="Submit Weight">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```